# How to reduce the loading time of a function in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my [site](http://attila-naghi.com/register). The idea is when you select a country from the dd, by on change events its calls a function using AJAX, execute a query and return a json. Im using Codeigniter framework. So my question how to improve this code in order to reduce the loading time of the cities, by selectin a country ? yes i know im a little stubborn and i dont want to use counties :)

here is html code in the view:

```
<div class="select_zones">
Country:
<select name="country" id = 'country' style="width:220px;">
<option value = "-1" selected="selected">Select a country</option>
<?php 
    foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option value = "'.$value->id.'-'.$value->country_type.'">'.trim($value->name).'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select_zones">
    <div class="city" style ="display:none;">
        City:
        <select name="city" id ="city" style="width:220px;">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the js code:

```
$("#country").select2(); 
    $("#city").select2();
    $("#country").change(function(){
        $("#city option").remove();
        value = $(this).val();
        value = value.split("-");
        $.post( "register/get_cities_from_dd", { country_type: value[1]})
            .done(function( data ) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i in obj) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        text     : obj[i].name,
                        value    : obj[i].id
                    }).prependTo('#city');
                }
        });
        $(".city").show();
    });
```

this is the function from the controller:

```
   public function get_cities_from_dd(){

        $country_type = $_POST['country_type'];
        $cities = $this->register_model->get_cities($country_type);
        echo json_encode($cities);

    }
```

and finally the model:

```
 public function get_cities($country_type){

        return $this->db->query("SELECT id,name FROM cities WHERE city_type = '".$country_type."' ORDER BY `name` DESC ")->result();

    }
```

Comment: don't understand the question, but I'll just remark that the animations make me real dizzy. It's WayTooMuch™

Comment: your code is wideopen for sql injection.

Comment: @r3wt i don;t understand your reply

Comment: @MightyPork as you can see it takes to much time to load the cities from a specific country. How can i reduce the loading time ??

Comment: @r3wt I know, im starting to develop it last day, so I dont have the time to improve all the functionalities

Comment: You are returning 55,000 rows to a select list. You should consider filtering by state/province, then by city based on the selected state/province. There's no way to improve your performance given this approach, at all.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there must be a better solution :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't really evaluate it. My whole browser crashed after I tried to select a city.

Comment: @MightyPork because the amount of data which is parsed by json

Comment: @Chester  no, it's because of poor practices and sending far more data than needed. `I don't have time` is a terrible excuse

Comment: @charlietfl , so how can i improve my code ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy already told you how to improve it

Comment: Well, looking at the cities, you have a lot of tiny villages and one-house "villages" in the list. Perhaps get a better list with fewer cities / towns. Or, just let people select OR enter custom, if it's not available in the list.

Comment: ok, so where can i get a list of counties/regions and cities? Can somebody give me a link or smth. in sql, or csv format or other ?

Comment: Try google, I have only a CSV list of countries, capitals, areas and populations. Not cities :(

Comment: can you send me via email ? I would really appreaciate it

Comment: it's only countries, you want cities, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading way too much data, there is no way to improve this (other than changing it completely like suggested in the comments to your question). Also note that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would have been a better place for this question.

The best solution to your problem would be e.g. [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) or any equivalent software that was designed to auto-complete huge amounts of data. The user could simply start typing the name of the city and the software could complete it. I'd use a text field, wait for at least two characters and insert a e.g. 250ms timeout (request animation frame) between each key stroke before hitting the server again. But I'd still limit the number of results to e.g. 25 or 100 if you will.

If you still want to stick to your current implementation and don't want to listen to the many comments that were given to your question (like the serious SQL injection problem) go for prepared HTML files.

We have a directory `countries` that contains the options for each country, totally rendered, no need to do anything other than loading from the server:

```
/countries/at.html
/countries/us.html
```

Current HTML document:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="at">Austria</option>
  <option value="us">United States</option>
</select>
<select id="cities" name="cities">
  <option selected>Please Select a Country</option>
</select>
```

Our jQuery:

```
$("#country").change(function (event) {
  $("#citites").load("/cities/" + this.value + ".html");
});
```

Still, way too much for the browser.